# Как отловить сообщения с тегом d в logcat андроид?

Tags: java, android, logcat

Доброго времени суток господа.
В общем стоит задача взять логи выполнения приложения и отправить их по почте разработчику.
Думал что с отправкой проблемы будут, но ни как не с отловом логов.
Есть код:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GetLogs {

    public static String get(){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d all");

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            Log.d("Error getting logs");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

Класс просто ловит и возвращает логи, проблема в теге по которому он их ловит.
"logcat -d all" по идее должен отловить все логи с тегом d, но те логи что вывожу вручную принципиально не ловит. Вывожу так (ну мало ли):

```
Log.d("MyLog","TEST");
```

Метод выше возвращает следующее:

```
    --------- beginning of system
01-26 08:42:37.797  1813  1827 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
    --------- beginning of main
01-26 08:42:37.797  1813  1827 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 8 lines
01-26 08:42:37.805  1813  1829 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 1 line
01-26 08:42:37.900  1813  1831 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 24 lines
01-26 08:42:39.136  1813  1832 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 9 lines
01-26 08:43:19.769  1813  1848 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 15 lines
01-26 08:43:20.075  1813  1813 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 6 lines
01-26 08:57:52.638  1974  1974 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 27 lines
01-26 08:57:52.670  1974  1988 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
01-26 08:57:52.670  1974  1988 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 8 lines
01-26 08:57:52.678  1974  1990 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 1 line
01-26 08:57:52.699  1974  1992 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 39 lines
01-26 08:57:53.029  1974  1993 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 9 lines
01-26 09:02:55.283  2073  2073 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 17 lines
01-26 09:02:55.317  2073  2087 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gms.chimera
01-26 09:02:55.317  2073  2087 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 8 lines
01-26 09:02:55.322  2073  2089 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 1 line
01-26 09:02:55.347  2073  2091 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expire 3 lines
     --------- beginning of crash
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime: Process: tanat.androidtesttask, PID: 2073
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tanat.androidtesttask/tanat.androidtesttask.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at tanat.androidtesttask.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
01-26 09:02:55.355  2073  2073 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
01-26 09:03:15.533  2102  2102 I chatty  : uid=10080(tanat.androidtesttask) expir
```

По сути это то что нужно ЕСЛИ добавить еще те логи что пишу я.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: по моему [тут все не так просто](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975844/5330439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я использую такую конструкцию:

```
adb logcat -s "TAGNAME"
```